# 'cv2' has no attribute 'calcOpticalFlowHS'

Tags: python, opencv

So, i want to track object using Horn and Schunk alogorithm..and this is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a VideoCapture object to read from the video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mp4')

# Read the first frame
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
frame1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Define the parameters for optical flow calculation
lk_params = dict(winSize=(15, 15),
                 maxLevel=2,
                 criteria=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))

# Loop over all frames in the video
while True:
    # Read the next frame
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Convert to grayscale
    frame2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Calculate optical flow using Horn and Schunck method
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowHS(frame1_gray, frame2_gray, 0.5, (32, 32), 3)

    # Compute the magnitude and angle of the optical flow vectors
    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1])

    # Threshold the magnitude to detect moving objects
    threshold = 25
    mask = np.zeros_like(frame1_gray)
    mask[mag > threshold] = 255

    # Apply morphological operations to remove noise and fill gaps
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    # Display the resulting mask
    cv2.imshow('Object detection', mask)

    # Update the previous frame
    frame1_gray = frame2_gray.copy()

    # Exit the loop if the 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the VideoCapture object and destroy all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But i am getting an Attribute Error stating module 'cv2' has no attribute 'calcOpticalFlowHS'..
Please help!

I was expecting the code to detect the objects in the video.

Comment: `cv.calcOpticalFlowHS` was removed in OpenCV 3.x

Comment: typo error it is cv2.CalcOpticalFlowHS